# Make a new file who's name is a directory path

Tags: c#

I'm creating a csv file with a bunch of data. This file is going to be pushed up to another location and its name is going to be used to put it in the directory it belongs in. I need to create the filename to mimic a directory, without actually using that directory.

I'm using the below, basically "outputDirectory" is where the file should live, everything after it needs to be part of the filename.

```
String fileName = outputDirectory + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-mm-hh") + "//" + app + "//" + client +"//" + site +"//" + unit + ".csv";
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName, false))
{
    foreach (AFValue AFval in AFvals)
    {
        string tagname = AFval.PIPoint.Name;
        string timestamp = AFval.Timestamp.ToString();
        string value = AFval.Value.ToString();
        var newLine = string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", tagname, timestamp, value);
        sw.Write(newLine);
        sw.Write(Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

So right now this code is throwing an exception with

'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Output\2019-53-01\app\client\site\Unit.csv'.'

I need it to create a file in 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Output\' called

2019-53-01\app\client\site\Unit.csv'.'

Any ideas?

Comment: Additionally, for reference, you are "escaping" forward slashes which is not needed. You only need to escape backslashes (\\). You can also avoid needing to escape back slashes by prefixing your string with an `@`. E.g. `var tmp = @"a\b\c";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the slash **** in the file name.

Here is an excerpt from [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file)

Use any character in the current code page for a name, including Unicode characters and characters in the extended character set (128–255), except for the following:

The following reserved characters:

- < (less than)
- > (greater than)
- : (colon)
- " (double quote)
- / (forward slash)
- \ (backslash)
- | (vertical bar or pipe)
- ? (question mark)
- - (asterisk)
- Integer value zero, sometimes referred to as the ASCII NUL character.
- Characters whose integer representations are in the range from 1 through 31, except for alternate data streams where these characters are allowed. For more information about file streams, see File Streams.
- Any other character that the target file system does not allow.

Comment: @Marie Agreed, as far as I can tell OP is correct. If he's wrong leave a comment, otherwise this post is great